# Black background while copying image from Firefox

Tags: delphi, firefox, jpeg, clipboard

An image is copied from Firefox into the Clipboard. My program gets it from clipboard and saves as a JPEG image. For some reason the image is saved with a black background. If I open the same URL in IE and copy the image into the Clipboard, the image is saved correctly by my program. I am using Delphi 7.

I also tried to copy the image from Firefox into Microsoft Paint and again the black background. Does anyone has a tip in how to handle such problem.

Comment: So the question now is: how to detect transparency in a DIB? Firefox just puts a DIB in the Clipboard. The original image is a PNG. I would like to know how can I detect in the DIB if it has transparency or not.

Comment: If you wish to refine your question, then edit it. You don't have enough repuration to edit other people's questions or answers, but you always have enough to edit your own.

Comment: It's a limitation in how Firefox copies things to the clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the original image is transparent? If so, you should be aware that JPEGs can't handle transparency. Try switching the output image type and seeing if you program magically goes away.

Comment: Does not work. I tried saving to PNG and GIF to no avail. The problem lies when the DIB is loaded in a TPicture. Somehow I must determine it the image has transparency or not and handle it. That's my question.

Comment: TBH, I don't see why you're copying things to clipboards and such -- can't you just fetch the image from the url, thus cutting out the firefox middle man, which is potentially causing problems?

Comment: My program acts as a clipboard catcher. He does not see Firefox but what is in the Clipboard. The problem is how to handle an image copied from Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

If you get the same background in your program and Paint, then that tells me this is something to do with Firefox, and thus it is not necessarily your problem to solve.

Since you're concerned about the background color, I guess the image you're copying has transparent elements to it. So tell me: What color *should* be there? A JPEG image can't have transparent parts, so every pixel must have *some* color. Firefox apparently chooses to put black there; how is that not a correct choice and Internet Explorer's is?

I wonder what color background you get when you paste into a more capable graphics program than Paint, such as Gimp or Photoshop. I would expect those programs to consider multiple [clipboard formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649013.aspx) and choose the most appropriate format, so they might choose a format that accommodates transparency when it's available. Your program and Paint, on the other hand, probably just use the `cf_Bitmap` format, which of course can't have transparent pixels, so they get whatever the copying program opted to use to fill in the blank space.

By the way, both Firefox and Internet Explorer allow you to drag an image directly from the browser to the desktop or other folder window to save the original image. Maybe that makes your program unnecessary?

Comment: Rob, my program catches the clipboard content when something is copied into it. Firefox just puts the image in two formats, DIB and another one I don't remember right now. I am dealing with the DIB one.

Comment: Rob, I don't know if here is the right place to answer your question. I am new at StackOverflow. The other format that Firefox puts in the Clipboard seems a native one:  application/x-moz-nativeimage. I have to stick to CF_DIB.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a slightly old question, but I've just come across the same issue in Firefox v9.

Use the following workaround: save the image in question to your computer, then copy the file in explorer and paste in the program you want to use (in my case I pasted into word).